# PHP echoing an image from a MariaDB BLOB

Tags: php, mariadb, blob

I have a PHP/MariaDB application that has some images stored as BLOBs. I recently moved the app to a cloud hosted service and the behaviour of viewing images is broken. PHP serving a GET request for an image is this:

```
    require(__DIR__.'/../include/db/MyDatabase.php');
    
    try {
        $data = (new MyDatabase())->getImage(htmlspecialchars($date));
        header('Content-Type:'.$data['mime']);
        header('Content-Length:'.strlen($data['image']));
        echo $data['image'];
    }catch(Exception $e){
        header('Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        echo json_encode([ 'errors' => [ $e->getMessage() ]]);
    }
```

`$data` is an associative array with the image's mime type, binary, and a date that the image is for. When I was hosting the app on my server, this works fine. That's Ubuntu 22.04 with PHP 8.1 and MySQL PDO driver mysqlnd 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14.

On the cloud hosting service, they are using PHP 8.2 and MySQL PDO driver 3.1.21 and images don't work. The Content Length and Type are set:

[image: Content Length and Type]

But the image isn't displayed:

[image: Broken Image]

I don't know if versions of things make a difference but I'm drawing a blank on what might be wrong.

Edit: Just for comparison, the request on the left results in an image coming back, the request on the right doesn't:

[image: Browser Dev Tools]

I don't really know what to look for, but the same code is in both environments

Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong, or where to look?

Comment: Inspect the response using the developer tools in your favourite web browser. If your code did run correctly on your local computer, then it is unlikely we will find something in there.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In the future, I recommend not storing images in the database.  Instead, put them in files and emit `<img src=path-to-jpg>` in the HTML.  Simple, fast, no mime issues, avoids hiccups like you are having.

Comment: The value of `Content-Length` is identical in both versions shown - but does the actual amount of bytes received really match that? Maybe you got something else in the data stream, a rogue BOM perhaps. When you look at the received request _bodies_, do they appear to start with the same bytes/values, or are there differences?

Comment: @CBroe Good point, no, the non-working one is only about 6KB as opposed to the working 1.4MB. What would that indicate?

Comment: Not sure :-) I mean, you are setting the Content-Length header as `strlen($data['image'])`, so that would indicate what you read from the database, is correct up until that point. The headers in the right half indicate that LiteSpeed is involved - as a proxy server before the actual application server, presumably? Maybe that is somehow messing with things.

Comment: Can you just try and place an `exit;` after `echo $data['image'];`, and see if that changes anything? (Not much hope that it will do, but just to be sure.)

Comment: @CBroe No difference after adding `exit();`. The web server will serve me a static .png file, but this image data is coming from a call to a php file: `image.php?date=2023-06-02` so maybe LiteSpeed is not liking that it's image data coming from something that doesn't have a typical image file extension? Clutching at straws but LiteSpeed is my biggest suspicion right now

Comment: You might check if test.jpg is a valid jpg-file after doing `curl -v http://youserver?image.php?date=2023-06-02 --output test.jpg`

Comment: try adding     flush(); ob_flush();   after the echo. See if this helps can be buffer related.

Comment: Just save the response to a file and open it with a hex  editor.

Comment: Just another idea: Did you try to **not** set the `Content-Length` header at all? The server might compress the data for submission and thus the content length could be off. ‍♂️

Comment: Also you can try set encoding to  utf-8, something like this:
`header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8'); `

Comment: @DmitryLeiko A charset for binary data?

Comment: Setting a charset doesn't make sense for binary data.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your cloud hosting provider has limited the amount of memory a PHP script can utilize - since you're loading the entire image into memory the PHP script will at least use as much memory as the image is big.

Comment: How was the data migrated between servers? Because I've seen many instances of "dump to SQL and load" silently corrupt binary data. Try running a simple `SHA1()` query on both sides and confirm that the data matches in both systems.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same identical code produce two different results in two different environments usually means that there is a version discrepancy, or, more likely (in your case, I think) a configuration mismatch.

I think your best bet is going to be to have a look at/change the [Max Dynamic Response Body Size](https://www.litespeedtech.com/docs/webserver/config/tuning#maxDynRespSize) option for litespeed:

> Specifies the maximum body size of a dynamically generated response.

I think this applies because you're calling a `.php` script and not a file with a common extension that is known to produce static data (like `.png` for example).

Your code looks somewhat correct, although the `htmlspecialchar` is a bit weird for making a request to a database. Usually you only use `htmlspecialchar` to output untrusted data to a browser client.

Comment: Thanks. `htmlspecialchar` was a spree of fixes in order to make Snyk happy :) apparently I knew less about XSS than I thought I did

Comment: @Jobbo Where you able to track down the issue?

Comment: @Jobbo actually `htmlspecialchar` fixes XSS problems and you might want to use it when you store data as well, if there are some third-party UIs relying on your data, whose security standards are lower than yours. In that situation, you can protect them from XSS. But in general what's necessary is to protect your data at display time.

Comment: It is not recommended to save data in its escaped form. Although it is easier to deal with potential malicious data, it makes it hard to go back (from the escaped to the raw data that is).

Answer (score 1):

Since your algorithm is deterministic and it operates differently on different server setups, the issue may be:

- OS version difference
- OS setting difference
- DB version difference
- DB setting difference
- PHP version difference
- data difference

A solution to these problems is to be very consistent with how you operate with the OS, DB, PHP and webserver and that would minimalize the chance of having this kind of problem.

However, if you want to find out what exactly caused your problem, then you can set up either a docker environment, a virtual machine or an actual machine to have W (where W is the working settings in terms of OS, PHP, DB and data) and see whether you can reproduce success on this copy of settings. If not, then fix the issues that preventing it from working, it should not be difficult, given the fact that your starting point is the working settings.

Now, when you have managed to make your W settings portable, on your experimental setup gradually drift away from W settings to F (failed) settings, one step at a time (change PHP's version first, for example) and see which setting/configuration/data step converts your setting from working to not working. That's where your bug is located (or, more precisely, there is a bug, hopefully the only bug).

Comment: Upvoted, I forgot about the possibility of different data!

Answer (score 0):

Tested using litespeed, this works:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
//header('Content-Length: '.filesize("test.png"));
$data = readfile("test.png");
// echo $data;  // EDIT: This is wrong because it outputs the size of the picture, and that was not supposed to happen..
exit;
```

It seems you do not need to send the `Content-Length`

I noticed one strange behaviour...

When doing `curl http://localhost/test/image.php --output test2.png`, my output image was 5 bytes larger than my input image.

Examining revealed that the length of the original image (`21215`) was added the the test2.png file.

```
root@ubuntu45:/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/test# hexdump -C test2.png | tail -3
000052d0  71 9d ec 00 00 00 00 49  45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82 32  |q......IEND.B`.2|
000052e0  31 32 31 35                                       |1215|
000052e4
root@ubuntu45:/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/test# hexdump -C test.png | tail -3
000052c0  04 1a 81 16 00 00 00 01  26 fd ff 10 06 28 5b a5  |........&....([.|
000052d0  71 9d ec 00 00 00 00 49  45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82     |q......IEND.B`.|
000052df
```

EDIT: I commented one of the lines in my PHP (and added comment to it) because it was outputting the length of the image.

tested using: `LiteSpeed/1.7.18 Open (BUILD built: Tue Aug 29 12:59:39 UTC 2023)` on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Comment: _I noticed one strange behaviour..._ you get that behaviour because `readfile` doesn't return the data as a string but rather the size of the file that was read.

Comment: ok, that explains. I need more practice in PHP 

Answer (score 0):

simply use `base64_encode`

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo base64_encode($data['image']);
```